# Swift IOS notification with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-уведомления

Обработчик получение уведомлений срабатывает лишь если приложение активно. Если приложение отключено оно не срабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
func showNotification(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any] ){
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

print("body: \(userInfo)")

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = userInfo["name"] as! String
content.body = userInfo["surename"] as! String
content.sound = .default

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval:20, repeats: false)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "firenotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

center.add(request) { (error) in
    if error != nil{
        print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")")
    }
    else{
        print("complete")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: вы имеете в виду, уведомление не показывается, если убить приложение? Приведенный код вполне работает, для его работы достаточно успешной отработки запроса `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда приложение убито/свёрнуто - срабатывает вот этот метод `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` в делегате, соответственно внутри этого метода и нужно, вам, делать обработку ответа.